# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' for Python Code

Tags: python, string, object

I get this when I try to run a code called NUT_check.py and this comes from line 69. I'm very unsure of what is happening as I didn't make this code myself, nor have I really used Python extensively. Line 69 is ending with a line of hyphens to mark it

```
import sys
import struct
from struct import pack
import os
from util import *
import string
import math

nut = open(sys.argv[1], "rb+")

NTWU = readu32be(nut)
Version = readu16be(nut)
fileTotal = readu16be(nut)
nut.seek(0x10)
paddingFix = 0
for i in range(fileTotal):
    if i > 0:
            paddingFix = paddingFix + headerSize
    fullSize = readu32be(nut)
    nut.seek(4,1)
    size = readu32be(nut)
    headerSize = readu16be(nut)
    nut.seek(2,1)
    mipsFlag = readu16be(nut)
    gfxFormat = readu16be(nut)
    if NTWU == 0x4E545755:
            width = readu16be(nut)
            height = readu16be(nut)
    if NTWU == 0x4E545033:
            width2 = readByte(nut)
            width1 = readByte(nut)
            height2 = readByte(nut)
            height1 = readByte(nut)
    numOfMips = readu32be(nut)
    nut.seek(4,1)
    offset1 = (readu32be(nut) + 16)
    offset2 = (readu32be(nut) + 16)
    offset3 = (readu32be(nut) + 16)
    nut.seek(4,1)
    if headerSize == 0x60:
            size1 = readu32be(nut)
            nut.seek(12,1)
    if headerSize == 0x70:
            size1 = readu32be(nut)
            nut.seek(0x1C,1)
    if headerSize == 0x80:
            size1 = readu32be(nut)
            nut.seek(0x2C,1)
    if headerSize == 0x90:
            size1 = readu32be(nut)
            nut.seek(0x3C,1)
    eXt = readu32be(nut)
    nut.seek(12,1)
    GIDX = readu32be(nut)
    nut.seek(6,1)
    skinNum = readByte(nut)
    fileNum = readByte(nut)
    nut.seek(4,1)
    print("Slot Number %i Texture id %s,%i has %i mipmaps. Format is %i" % (skinNum/4,hex(fileNum),fileNum,mipsFlag,gfxFormat))
    if i == 0:
            offsetHeader = offset3
    if i > 0:
            offset1 += paddingFix
            offsetHeader += 0x80
    backNTime = nut.tell()
    nut.seek(offsetHeader)
    fileStr = ("%d"  % fileNum)
    outfile = open("Convert" + "/" + fileStr + ".gtx", "wb")
    outfile.write("\x47\x66\x78\x32\x00\x00\x00\x20\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x42\x4C\x4B\x7B\x00\x00\x00\x20\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x00\x9C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00") ----------------------------------------------
    outfile.write(nut.read(0x80))
    outfile.write("\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x02\x03\x1F\xF8\x7F\x21\xC4\x00\x03\xFF\x06\x88\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0A\x80\x00\x00\x10\x42\x4C\x4B\x7B\x00\x00\x00\x20\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0C\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")
    outfile.seek(0x50)
    outfile.write(struct.pack(">I",1))
    outfile.seek(0xf0)
    outfile.write(struct.pack(">I",size))
    outfile.seek(8,1)
    nut.seek(offset1)
    outfile.write(nut.read(size))
    outfile.write("\x42\x4C\x4B\x7B\x00\x00\x00\x20\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")
    outfile.close()
    nut.seek(backNTime)
nut.close()
```

Comment: Please try posting the full error message and try debugging the program yourself before asking others. Include your debugging efforts as well.

Comment: Your entire question could be minimized to the simple `open()` followed by the `write()` on line 69.

Comment: You might be trying to run Python 2 code in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're using python3 instead of python2.  If you continue to use python3, try changing the binary-ish string constants to be prefixed with `b`:

```
>>> outfile = open("/tmp/foo", "wb")
>>> outfile.write("\x47\x66\x78\x32\x00\x00\x00\x20\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x42\x4C\x4B\x7B\x00\x00\x00\x20\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x00\x9C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
>>> outfile.write(b"\x47\x66\x78\x32\x00\x00\x00\x20\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x42\x4C\x4B\x7B\x00\x00\x00\x20\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x00\x9C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")
64
>>>
```